# Grid in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, grid

How can I get the main grid (ContentElement) in windows phone 7 using only C# without getting it from the XAML using this.contentPanel

In other words, I'm developing a library which will add UI elements to the application and I want to add these elements to the main grid when the user request it (I don't want the user to pass it to me as parameter, I want to get it by code).

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you can do in XAML, you can do in code. To drive a Grid by code you need to add [column definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.columndefinitions.aspx) and [row definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.rowdefinitions.aspx). 
Then you can add additional controls to the Grid [Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx) collection, and place in the proper "cell" by using the attached properties [Grid.Row](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.row.aspx) and [Grid.Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.column.aspx).

Here a code example in adding a control:

```
TextBox txt=new TextBlock();
txt.Text="Hallo";
contentPanel.Children.Add(txt);
Grid.SetRow(txt, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(txt, 1);
```

You can have a mixed approach too, by creating row/cols definition in XAML, and just add controls in code.

Comment: But I don't want from the user to pass "myGrid" to me , I want to get it by myseld

Comment: Ensure your "contentPanel" is a grid, and use it in place on myGrid. I update the code now.

Comment: how can I get contentPanel ? .. The user will pass it to me?